# Java, getting data from a Derby database and converting each row into a Json object

Tags: java, json, jdbc, derby

I am tinkering with Java and Derby database, and wrote code to get all the rows from a derby database (netbeans integrated database) and create a JSON object from it.

```
try {
      PreparedStatement statement = this.con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM PURCHASEORDERS");
      ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
      JSONObject objectJson = new JSONObject();
      while(result.next()){
      for (int x=1;x<(result.getMetaData().getColumnCount())+1;x++)
      {
          if(result.getMetaData().getColumnType(x)==java.sql.Types.INTEGER)
          {objectJson.put(result.getMetaData().getColumnName(x), result.getInt(x));}
          if(result.getMetaData().getColumnType(x)== java.sql.Types.VARCHAR)
          {objectJson.put(result.getMetaData().getColumnName(x), result.getString(x));}
          if(result.getMetaData().getColumnType(x)== java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN)
          {objectJson.put(result.getMetaData().getColumnName(x), result.getBoolean(x));}
      }
      }
      System.out.println(objectJson);
```

Here is what the output is

```
{"STATUS":"ordered","DEPARTMENTCODE":"Enterfake","COMPLETEDSTATUS":true,"PURCHASEID":4,"DELIVERYATTENTION":"fake"}
```

which is the last row of the database. My question is why is it giving me only the last row? and How can I make it so that it gives me all the rows?
Any Ideas?

Comment: Create a new JsonObject at each iteration of the loop, and add it to a List<JSONObject>. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Comment: I m unfamiliar with lists
I tried List<JSONObject> list = new JSONObject();
at the end of the loop i added this bit 
    list.add(objectJson);
this is what I get
[{"purchaseid":1},{"departmentcode":"Enter"},{"status":"ordered"},...........

it creates a new object for each column element and creates a list. any other way i can get like the one i showed uptop but for all the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put an object to JSONObject with same key, then the previous values with that key will get overwritten, not added (because a JSON object can not have multiple keys with same name).

To get it working, create a list and then add that list to your JSONObject

Comment: I did that and it gives me a list of individual objects like :
[{"purchaseid":1}, {"departmentcode":"Enter"}, {"status":"ordered"}, {"deliveryattention":"Enter"}, {"completedstatus":true}, {"purchaseid":2}, {"departmentcode":"Enter"}, {"status":"ordered"}, {"deliveryattention":"Enter"}, {"completedstatus":true}, {"purchaseid":4}, {"departmentcode":"Enterfake"}, {"status":"ordered"}, {"deliveryattention":"fake"}, {"completedstatus":true}]

I need it like 

{"STATUS":"ordered","DEPARTMENTCODE":"Enterfake","COMPLETEDSTATUS":true,"PURCHASEID":4,"DELIVERYATTENTION":"fake"}
Any other ideas?

Comment: Before the loop create a list of JSONObject like List<JSONObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();

Then inside the loop, create a new JSONObject instance
JSONObject singleObject = new JSONObject (like you had before).

At the end of your loop, add the singleObject to the JSONObject list.
objects.add(singleObject);